# Set PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, eloquent

Is it possible to set `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` in Eloquent ORM?

i tried adding `database.attr_errmode` using `setContainer`, tried adding `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`, `attr_mode` to `addConnection` nothing worked. 
I want to `try/catch` fatal errors on missing cols, duplicate entries etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your database configuration:

```
'mysql' => [
    [...]
    'options' => [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel came with a handler of all that kind of error is up to you to customize that.
the default behavior when that type of exception are throw they are handle by the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class, you customize it to catch any type of exception that your application throwrn.

like you want to `try/catch` when there are not found model you can handle that by catching the `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class` exception type.

you can read more at Laravel Error Handling

You can catch any error of type QueryException which are type of exception that are thrown for many type of MySQL violation and you can handler this type of error by customizing the render method of the Handler class

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
        return response()->view('views.to.be.rendered', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```